# Error:Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Warning

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my app  I have been working to import and export the database.

I have imported some files which is required for this functionality but when i try to run the app in simulator the errors listed below occurs. I can't understand which type of errors are these. so plz help me solve this problem.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      -[NSData(NSDataExtension) gzipInflate] in NSData+CocoaDevUsersAdditions.o
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      -[NSData(NSDataExtension) gzipInflate] in NSData+CocoaDevUsersAdditions.o
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      -[NSData(NSDataExtension) gzipInflate] in NSData+CocoaDevUsersAdditions.o
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      -[NSData(NSDataExtension) gzipDeflate] in NSData+CocoaDevUsersAdditions.o
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      -[NSData(NSDataExtension) gzipDeflate] in NSData+CocoaDevUsersAdditions.o
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      -[NSData(NSDataExtension) gzipDeflate] in NSData+CocoaDevUsersAdditions.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You didn't include the libz.tbd where those functions are. Select the project node, select your target, go to the Build Phases tab, expand "Link Binaries With Libraries", add libz.dylib, and try again.

Comment: Yes, it works. But why error only occurred when I do archive!

Comment: As of Xcode 7, this is still the right answer but the library is now called "libz.tbd".

Comment: @Jano Thanks alot . U saved my time

Answer (score 1):

Add libz.dylib to your framework, it will work..

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, and thanks to Jano, it was resolved after I added the Libz.dylib to the project.