# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_deflate", referenced from PlatCompress(enumCompressOperation, CompressCookie*, void*, long) in libMo.a

Tags: iphone, ios, sybase, sup

I'm doing native iOS application using SUP.As per documentation; i have included the library and given the link path in Xcode.
While building getting following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      PlatCompress(enumCompressOperation, CompressCookie*, void*, long) in         libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      PlatCompress(enumCompressOperation, CompressCookie*, void*, long) in libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
  "_deflateInit_", referenced from:
      StartCompression(enumCompressOperation, unsigned char, long (*)(void*, void*, long), void*, void**) in libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
  "_deflateParams", referenced from:
      StartCompression(enumCompressOperation, unsigned char, long (*)(void*, void*, long), void*, void**) in libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      PlatCompress(enumCompressOperation, CompressCookie*, void*, long) in libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      PlatCompress(enumCompressOperation, CompressCookie*, void*, long) in libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
  "_inflateInit_", referenced from:
      StartCompression(enumCompressOperation, unsigned char, long (*)(void*, void*,  long), void*, void**) in libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help me how to solve this error.I'm new to native iOS development using SUP.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error:Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752127/errorapple-mach-o-linker-id-warning)

Comment: Got sol from here(now no build error):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752127/errorapple-mach-o-linker-id-warning 

Thanks.

Answer (score 155):

I also had a same error.

Add **libz.dylib** to framework from the target -> Build Phases tab -> Link Binaries With Libraries,

hope that will work for you.

Note: If **libz.dylib** not found, try adding **libz.tbd**

Comment: what is libz.dylib & what does it do?

Comment: Worked for me on Xcode7, iOS 9.1. My lacking libs were libz.tbd and libsqlite3.tbd

Comment: there is no "libz.dylib" but add libz.tbd and works  :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dhaval. Also can you please help me understand what is libz.tbd and how it has resolved this issue.

Comment: @GJDK libz is a library for zip and unzip functionality. The above symbols _deflate,  _inflate etc are from this library.

Answer (score 45):

Starting with Xcode 7, instead of adding libz.dylib, you should do this:

- Go to the project `Build Settings` tab
- Search for `Other Linker Flags`
- Add `-lz` as a linker flag (see screenshot)
- In the `Product` menu, select `Clean` before building again

[image: lz link option]

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my life :)

Comment: getting the same issue in Xcode 8.2.1 for adding a custom framework in a application .... pleasehelp

Comment: Please add an explanation as to why this resolves the problem.

Comment: @ChuckKrutsinger I know that the manual for `ld` explains the `-l[x]` flag tells the linker how to find the `lib[x].dylib` (in this case, libz.dylib). Somebody who understands this issue better than me should add an explanation. I just stumbled across the solution after other answers here didn't work, and posted what I did.

Comment: still true for Xcode 9. Either use flags or add the framework would work.

Comment: It is working but be sure to view all settings in Xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137698/1144011

Answer (score 19):

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

```
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      PlatCompress(enumCompressOperation, CompressCookie*, void*, long) in         libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      PlatCompress(enumCompressOperation, CompressCookie*, void*, long) in libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
  "_deflateInit_", referenced from:
      StartCompression(enumCompressOperation, unsigned char, long (*)(void*, void*, long), void*, void**) in libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
  "_deflateParams", referenced from:
      StartCompression(enumCompressOperation, unsigned char, long (*)(void*, void*, long), void*, void**) in libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      PlatCompress(enumCompressOperation, CompressCookie*, void*, long) in libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      PlatCompress(enumCompressOperation, CompressCookie*, void*, long) in libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
  "_inflateInit_", referenced from:
      StartCompression(enumCompressOperation, unsigned char, long (*)(void*, void*,  long), void*, void**) in libMo.a(tlplatcompress.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I had also the same problem,I think you didn't include the **libz.dylib library**.

To do so:

1. go to target section
2. Build Phases tab
3. Link Binaries With Libraries
4. click on + button
5. search libz.dylib
6. clcik on add button.

Comment: Nicely answered. Deep thought. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

1.go to target section

2.Build Phases tab

3.Link Binaries With Libraries

4.click on + button

5.search libz.tbd (or libz.dylib)

6.click on add button.

Comment: Your answer is no different to the other answers, so why have you posted it?

Comment: Only difference i have made is "5.search libz.tbd (or libz.dylib)" I think  libz.tbd is the new name for libz.dylib