# Other Linker Flags missing in Xcode Build Settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, linker-flags

As the title reads, I go into my Build Settings for my app, and search for "Other Linker Flags", nothing is returner. If I even search simply "Other", there is no "Other Linker Flags" section. I've seen other instances of this happening online, but have found no solutions. How can I find Other Linker Flags?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Make sure you click "All" at the top instead of "Basic". `OTHER_LDFLAGS` is the same thing as Other Linker Flags. Have fun!