# errors while integrating google analytics with ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cordova, google-analytics

I've been trying to integrate google analytics for 5 days now with a phonegap app but with no luck, lastly I found a solution on stackoverflow which is adding this code to my mainviewcontrolar.m

```c
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 // View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
 // you can do so here.
 // Initialize tracker.

 [super viewWillAppear:animated];


 // returns the same tracker you created in your app delegate
 // defaultTracker originally declared in AppDelegate.m
 id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

 // manual screen tracking
 [tracker sendView:@"Home Screen"];
  }
```

but this did not work, everytime I try it i get errors

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

please tell me what to do, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

On your project "Targets", at "Build Phases", you need to add libGoogleAnalytics.a in "Link Binary With Libraries"

Comment: i did, and i get theses errors


Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(NSData+zlib.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(NSData+zlib.o)
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(NSData+zlib.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(NSData+zlib.o)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752127/errorapple-mach-o-linker-id-warning and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version of Google Analytics, you'll need to add `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a`, not `libGoogleAnalytics.a` as bogdanh mentioned.